# Create a connection using FileTransferFTP

Tags: 7

I want to create a FTP connection using the `FileTransferFTP` class.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code used to create an FTP connection is similar to the following one.

```
try {
  $ftp = FileTransferFTP::factory($jail, $settings);
  $ftp->connect();
  // Copy the files.
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  // An error happened.
}
```

`$jail` is the directory to which the operations are restricted. Any tentative to write files externally to this directory will raise a [FileTransferException](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!filetransfer!filetransfer.inc/class/FileTransferException/7) exception.

`$settings` contains:

- `$settings['username']`: The username
- `$settings['password']`: The password
- `$settings['advanced']['hostname']`: The hostname for the FTP server (default to localhost)
- `$settings['advanced']['port']`: The server port (default to 21)

[FileTransferFTP::factory()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!filetransfer!ftp.inc/function/FileTransferFTP%3a%3afactory/7) returns the instance of the sub-class that takes care of the file transfer, if there is one, or raises an exception, if there aren't sub-classes.

The code currently executed from `FileTransferFTP::factory()` in Drupal 7 is the following one.

```
  $username = empty($settings['username']) ? '' : $settings['username'];
  $password = empty($settings['password']) ? '' : $settings['password'];
  $hostname = empty($settings['advanced']['hostname']) ? 'localhost' : $settings['advanced']['hostname'];
  $port = empty($settings['advanced']['port']) ? 21 : $settings['advanced']['port'];

  if (function_exists('ftp_connect')) {
    $class = 'FileTransferFTPExtension';
  }
  else {
    throw new FileTransferException('No FTP backend available.');
  }

  return new $class($jail, $username, $password, $hostname, $port);
```

Future versions of the class could implement the method differently, and create different instances of the [FileTransferChmodInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!filetransfer!filetransfer.inc/interface/FileTransferChmodInterface/7) interface basing on different conditions.

In Drupal 8, the class has been renamed [Drupal\Core\FileTransfer\FTP](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!FileTransfer!FTP.php/class/FTP/8).

Comment: Doh, didn't notice `abstract` on the class :)